# Equal space between navigation icons

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

How to have facebook navigation like alignments in Bootstrap?

Run the code in full page.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm fixed-top" style="background-color: #ffdbae;">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="http://localhost/mp/"><i class="fas fa-book-open" style="font-size:40px; color:#00CED1;"></i></a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="http://localhost/mp/post"><i class="fas fa-pen-fancy" style="font-size:40px; color:#fff;"></i></a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="http://localhost/mp/settings"><i class="fas fa-sliders-h" style="font-size:40px; color:#fff;"></i></a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="http://localhost/mp/profile"><i class="fas fa-user" style="font-size:40px; color:#fff;"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

As facebook navigation icons have equal space between each other, how can I acheive it in my navigation?

> **Note**: If the screen gets bigger/shorter it should auto adjust them self.

Comment: Look into using flexbox or read more carefully the bootstrap documentation for examples and code http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navs/

Comment: Yep, as what @wlh said, pay attention to the docs, especially about usage of `.nav-fill` and `.nav-justified`.

Comment: @DavidLiang Tried both, but no change [JSFiddle of fill](http://jsfiddle.net/phkce20m/) and [JSFiddle of justified](http://jsfiddle.net/phkce20m/2/)

Comment: @Akshay: the `.navbar-nav` needs to set its width to 100%. You can style that or add the bootstrap utility class `.w-100` to `.navbar-nav` in both your fiddle examples and see them yourself. My comment should be the accepted answer shouldn't it? :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flexbox to evenly space each nav item:

```
.navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```css
.navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm fixed-top" style="background-color: #ffdbae;">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="http://localhost/mp/"><i class="fas fa-book-open" style="font-size:40px; color:#00CED1;"></i></a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="http://localhost/mp/post"><i class="fas fa-pen-fancy" style="font-size:40px; color:#fff;"></i></a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="http://localhost/mp/settings"><i class="fas fa-sliders-h" style="font-size:40px; color:#fff;"></i></a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="http://localhost/mp/profile"><i class="fas fa-user" style="font-size:40px; color:#fff;"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Navs in bs4 are already flex-based.  And they added spacing classes so there is no need to redefine the BS classes, just included the spacing modifiers in the markup.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler than I thought with no need to redefine the BS4 CSS.  I modified the navbar to use bs4 markup without the `ul` and `li`...seems cleaner this way

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm fixed-top" style="background-color: #ffdbae;">
  <div class="navbar-nav w-100 nav-justified">
    <a class="nav-item" href="http://localhost/mp/"><i class="fas fa-book-open" style="font-size:40px; color:#00CED1;"></i></a>
    <a class="nav-item" href="http://localhost/mp/post"><i class="fas fa-pen-fancy" style="font-size:40px; color:#fff;"></i></a>
    <a class="nav-item" href="http://localhost/mp/settings"><i class="fas fa-sliders-h" style="font-size:40px; color:#fff;"></i></a>
    <a class="nav-item" href="http://localhost/mp/profile"><i class="fas fa-user" style="font-size:40px; color:#fff;"></i></a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: No, I need like Facebook means, all the space should be occupied but equally

Comment: justified you mean? let me see what I can find

Comment: Yes, also see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51331191/equal-space-between-navigation-icons#comment89638350_51331191)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
   .navbar-nav {
      display: flex;
    }
    .nav-item {
      flex: 1;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 5px;
    }
```